Why I can't import the data from a csv file in mysql workbench?
I need to import the data in a csv file to an table in mysql workbench, but it keeps showing error.
I tried to convert the csv file to a json file, and importing from the json file the data showed up. But when I click "import" it tries to process but shows "0 records imported".
the data shows up in the import wizard
0 records imported with the json file
With the CSV file it shows this error. pls help

Theae are mysql workbench import wizard issues. Need to raise this with mysql support or alternatively try load data infile sql statement to import the csv version.

I converted my file it was in UTF-8(with BOM). Put it in UTF-8 through CotEditor and it worked perfectly.
